# How do I disable bold text in Roxterm terminal emulator?

Tags: linux, terminal

Moved from SO to SU:

I've combed the internet and read the roxterm man page to no avail. Can someone shed some light on this: I'm trying to disable bold text in roxterm. I personally think the bold text looks bad.

I'm assuming there's something I have to put in either the ~/.config/roxterm.sourceforge.net/Colours/theme file or ~/.Xresources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aspects:

1. possibly removing the terminal's ability to draw bold text
2. telling the applications running in the terminal to not use bold text

For the former, you probably will not have much success: roxterm lacks the configurability of xterm where this is done.  Rather, it assumes that the font provides the feature, and uses it if an application asks.

For applications, there are at least three types:

1. those using termcap/terminfo
2. those using their *own* database (GNU `ls` is the most commonly encountered)
3. hardcoded applications (those that simply write escape sequences).  groff does *this*, but if you set the environment variable `GROFF_NO_SGR`, that can be suppressed.  There are other cases.

If you can ignore the last, then for the first two it is possible to make modified terminal database entries.  Even the "termcap" applications on Linux almost always use ncurses' terminfo database (Slackware may still provide termcap...).  You could make custom terminal descriptions which do not use the SGR 1, e.g., `\E[1m` in terminfo syntax (the `bold` capability which also appears as *part* of the `sgr` capability).  At a minimum, that could be done with this, compiled with `tic`:

```
nobold|my custom,
    bold@, sgr@, use=xterm,
```

and setting `TERM` to "nobold".  Doing that defeats `ls`'s database as a side-effect.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I ended up just switching to xterm and got it looking decent with the config file I found at [https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Configure_xterm_Fonts_and_Colors_for_Your_Eyeball]